# Need to serialize this complex HashMap in Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to serialize a complex HashMap of this form in Java:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Question>> subsets = new HashMap();
```

Question is an object with:

```
String body;
boolean inversedCorrection;
```

I've tried the usual:

```
String jsonToString;
Gson gson = new Gson()

jsonToString = gson.toJson(subsets);
```

Obviously the HashMAp is populated.

I'm aware I need to use TokenType class to achieve this but the use and meaning isn't clear to me, I don't want just the solution, it will be great if someone could teach me what this class does and how to use it. I'm familiarized with generic types but I'm having trouble with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean `serialize` (i.e turn java object to json)?

Comment: Yes sorry, my bad.

Comment: It should work by default without extra `TokenType` info. What do you see after serializing your `Map` instance?

Comment: Idk why but is working now, the only difference is that before I tried from a Junit class and now I did from my Main class.